# Sync iPhone Without Charging

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, charging

Title says it all. Is there a way to sync an iPhone with iTunes (tethered) without charging it concurrently?

An answer below indicated that this was possible by either modifying or purchasing a modified sync cable. If anyone knows how to do either one, please feel free to answer.

Comment: It will likely depend on the pins you are using on the iPhone end. A modified cable should be able to cut the charge sense portion of the signal (or otherwise manipulate the call for charge signal) while allowing the sync portion of the USB signal to pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will likely depend on the pins you are using on the iPhone end. A modified cable should be able to cut the charge sense portion of the signal (or otherwise manipulate the call for charge signal) while allowing the sync portion of the USB signal to pass.

Comment: Do you know of a specific way to either purchase or modify a 30 pin/Lightning cable in this way?

Comment: I haven't done the research lately. The information on the 30 pin connector should be easily searchable. If that's your main concern, feel free to edit that into the main question. If I come across a good article, I'll link.